# Error trying to configure apache and django

Tags: django, apache

I'm trying to install a django 1.3 app on apache 2.2 with mod_wsgi on windows 7. I added the following lines to httpd.conf

```
Listen 8080
...

LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

Alias /static/ "C:/Users/.../my_app/my_app/static/"

<Directory "C:/Users/.../my_app/my_app/static">
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
<Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Users/.../my_app/my_app/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/Users/.../my_app/"

<Directory "C:/Users/.../my_app/my_app">
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  <Files>
<Directory>
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.settings')

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandlers()

path = 'C:/Users/.../my_app/my_app'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
```

The `wsgi.py` file is in the same folder as `settings.py` and `urls.py`

When I go to `localhost:8080` it says: 
**Not found** The requested URL / was not found on this server

Note: I'm totally new to apache, I don't know what i'm missing, some docs show a way to configure it and others show a completly diferent way to do the same thing.

Any ideas of what's wrong with this configuration.

Comment: What else is on the server and why are you listening on port 8080 rather than 80. Seems a bit odd to see you listening on a port other than 80 and you aren't using a VirtualHost. So not sure if problem is that you already have a VirtualHost for port 80 and don't have VirtualHost for port 8080 so when accessing port 8080 it will fallback to the port 80 VirtualHost. Amend you question with more detail as to what else is running on the server and whether have any VirtualHost definitions.

Comment: Can you throw in the apahce error logs that would be of great help?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Windows 7, my first guess is permissions. Anything past the "Users" folder is going to have weird permissions issues. When I develop anything on Windows locally, I always place the project in a root folder, like "C:/projects/django/my_project/". Also, make sure you look at the Windows Firewall settings (if anything, for debug, disable Windows Firewall for a mo, or better yet add a Firewall rule):

http://www.howtogeek.com/112564/how-to-create-advanced-firewall-rules-in-the-windows-firewall/

Honestly, half of my trouble with windows is making sure project and development settings are outside of core structures. Don't install services to "C:/Program Files" or make projects folder in "C:/Users".